# Xperia M dual stuck at boot screen after unlocking bootloader!

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, fastboot, bootloader, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-m-dual

Help needed it's urgent. So I have unlocked bootloader successfully via fastboot.
Everything went fine until the end without any error. So I disconnected the device from PC and rebooted it and now it is stuck at boot animation forever. It's the only phone I have now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your device should have probably reset  the phone after bootloader unlock, but I would still ask, have you tried booting into Recovery mode and doing hard reset (clearing data and all caches)?

Comment: That's bizarre because I never heard any device that doesn't have a Recovery Mode! May be I'm living in my own little world. Anyhow, hard reset is like factory reset done by booting into Recovery and doing all the necessary flush. I assume you can still boot into fastboot so try `fastboot -w`. It will clear `userdata` and `cache`.

Comment: Hahaha I'm never into stuff like that. So I don't know about these recovery and all. So are you sure about that fastboot -w? What will happen after that?

Comment: That command will clear `userdata` (all apps+app data+ Internal SD card stuff) and cache. Alternatively, you can issue `fastboot erase userdata` and then  `fastboot erase cache`.

Comment: Not working I'm getting errors like - not supported, FAILURE etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem for myself by re-locking the bootloader and then repair the device using Sony PC Companion. Device is again in mint condition ;)
I'll add a supporting link later.
Support links-

[(1) How to get into recovery mode in Xperia devices?](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/sony-xperia-m-recovery-mode-47917/)
[(2) How to repair software using Sony PC Companion on Windows and using Mac Bridge on OS X?](http://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-Ion/Detailed-Software-Repair-Instructions-using-Pc-Companion-Win-or/td-p/249946)